# Java SwingX 2023 - How to get all the files to array using FileSystemModel on JXTree?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingx, jxtree

I am having a hard time using FileSystemModel, or the SimpleFileSystemModel in JXTree. I know I could set a root for it, and it works just fine, but I wanted to have more functionality on using it. These functionalities that are missing that I would like to look forward to is:

- Changing the directory names of files Ex: (/Users//Documents/test.zip -> test.zip)
- I would also want to get all the files even in subfolders, so I can get the count of all files iterated.
- Drag and drop nodes (files)

I am also thinking if I should just understand the implementation of FileSystemModel and extend it?

The main problem here is these two in the list and not the drag and drop, but if someone knows how to implement drag and drop, it would much appreciated!.

[This image contains the problem from list no. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjqV0.png)

Thank you!

I tried Googling for this problem but I don't found any. I've also seen documentations for SwingX, and in wayback machine, but I couldn't really figure it out. Maybe I should just take my time to implement ways on my own?